# Migrating ubuntu; fetch manally installed packages to feed apt-get install

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, migration

#### Description:

This is somehow simple; I am migrating to an other computer.
I am going to take the opportunity to switch to the new 18.04 LTS from the 16.04 (on the old computer).

On the 16.04 I installed so many (!) libraries and packages manually using `apt-get`.

#### Question:

Is there a way to fetch these packages, in a text file for example, that I can copy and paste on the 18.04 to feed an `apt-get` command to install them back?

Comment: I wrote a guide and made a video about this in 2014. I'm sure the same process still applies. See https://techedemic.com/2014/10/01/offline-package-installs-using-dpkg-and-apt-get-ubuntudebianetc/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for the `apt-mark` command.

`apt-mark showmanual` will return a list of all packages marked `manual`.

There are two sets of `manual` packages, and they are all mixed together:

1. Packages you specified to apt (`sudo apt install foo` or `sudo apt-mark manual foo`) These are the top-level packages in your system. Everything else is a dependency. Usually your desktop metapackage is among these.
2. Packages installed by the Desktop installer during the initial installation of Ubuntu. This is a safety measure to prevent users from erroneously removing large slabs of their system when they remove their desktop metapackage.